# getting error in console when using fetch.catch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have the following code:

```
fetch(
  url,
  { ...data }
).then((response) => {
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
  return response.json();
}).then((response) => {
  resolve(response);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('error', error);
  reject(error);
});
```

When I perform a request and get a `404`, the `console.log('error')` line runs, but I still get an error int he console:

```
GET https://swapi.co/api/people/0/ 404 ()

Uncaught (in promise) Error
    at http.js:10
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, if the `catch()` block is running, why does it say `uncaught (in promise)`?

Comment: Because you reject something else immediately after that? `reject(error);`

Comment: what is `reject` ?

Comment: I suppose it is because you do `reject(error);` after your `console.log`. If you remove it ( `reject(error);`), what happens?

Comment: yea that's right, I just tested and that seems to be the problem. Thanks for the clarification. Anyone can post that as the answer and I'll accept

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `reject`, so the promise this points to will get rejected, and if you don't catch that that is uncaught. to resolve that see:

[What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)